# Coffeescript - How to convert a javascript into coffeescript in ruby on rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I have a button in my views in `test.html.erb` as follows

```
<button  id="Todo_full" onclick="showFullscreen(this);">Full size</button>
```

and its javascript is as follows:

```
    function showFullscreen(event)
    {
    var elem = document.getElementById('card_' + event.id);

        if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
        return elem.requestFullscreen();
        }
        else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) 
        {

        /* Firefox */
        return elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
        }
    }
```

When I keep the javascript code at the below of the `test.html.erb` file it works fine. 
And when I convert this code into coffeescript through http://js2.coffee/ and keep the code in `app/assets/javascript/test.coffee` which is as follows:

```
showFullscreen = (event) ->
  elem = document.getElementById('card_' + event.id)
  if elem.requestFullscreen
    return elem.requestFullscreen()
  else if elem.mozRequestFullScreen

    ### Firefox ###

    return elem.mozRequestFullScreen()
  return
```

It shows an error in console

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: showFullscreen is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):384)
```

Even when I use `window.onload = ->` at the top of coffeescript's code I get the same error in console.

Thank you

Comment: Those code snippets aren't quite equivalent. The JavaScript one is defining a *global* `showFullscreen` function whereas the CoffeeScript one is creating a local `showFullscreen` function inside a scope wrapper. Perhaps you want to say `@showFullScreen = (event) -> ...` or `window.showFullScreen = (event) -> ...`. Or better, don't use an `onclick` attribute at all, create local functions and bind them to elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're running into is the different scoping between JS and CoffeeScript. To get your code working, you need to scope your function globally on `window` or the CoffeeScript shorthand `@`.

From the [CoffeeScript docs](https://coffeescript.org/#lexical-scope):

> If you’d like to create top-level variables for other scripts to use,
>   attach them as properties on `window`.

Which for your function would look like:

```coffee
# Using window
window.showFullscreen = (event) ->
  elem = document.getElementById('card_' + event.id)
  ...

# Or using @
@showFullscreen = (event) ->
  elem = document.getElementById('card_' + event.id)
  ...
```

The CoffeeScript `@` is shorthand for `this` in JavaScript. So, in your example, because you're defining the function at the top level window scope `window == @`. Keep in mind that *within* your functions the scope will be different and `window != @`, and instead `@` will be scoped to whatever `this` is inside of your function. [This blog post has a nice explanation:](https://www.openmymind.net/2012/5/16/Ten-Features-I-Like-About-CoffeeScript)

> Speaking of `this`, CoffeeScript has a shortcut for it, the `@` symbol.
>   It's easy to write this off as meaningless syntactical sugar, but it
>   is useful. First, constructor parameters prefixed with `@` are converted
>   into properties:
>
> ```coffee
>  # CoffeeScript
>  class User
>    constructor: (@id) ->
> ```
>
> ```js
>  // JavaScript
>  function User(id) {
>    this.id = id;
>  }
> ```
>
> Beyond this though, it's a nice way to define class method:
>
> ```coffee
>  # CoffeeScript
>  class User
>    constructor: (@id) ->
>
>     @findById: (id) =>
>     ...
> ```
>
> ```js
>  // JavaScript
>  function User(id) {
>    this.id = id;
>   }
>  User.findById = function() {};
> ```
>
> Neither `@` nor the fat arrow `=>` mean that you don't have to worry about
>   the current meaning of `this` (or its alias `@`). They aren't silver
>   bullets, which isn't to say that they don't add value.

Comment: Thanks for the reply bro, but I quit working on ror technology now.

Comment: Awww bummer @shashiverma! RoR is still my fav :-) If you think this answer was helpful anyway, could you mark is at the correct answer for future viewers? Out of curiosity, what tech are you working with now?

Comment: sure why not, I have created an admin template in ror but I was always confused with pipelines, CoffeeScript, in which sequence we should import (or require) libraries. Now I am working on a javascript framework vuejs.